# How many transients is too many transients

Tags: transient

I am using transients on my Wordpress site, and we may end up with more than 1,000,000 transients in the worst case situation. I think 500,000 is more likely, but I was wondering if having too many transients could cause some performance issues? We keep them for 1 year, because the same requests keep being made throughout the year repeatedly. I know in terms of storage it won't be much of an issue, because a single transient don't take up much space.

Comment: That's a very long time for a very large number of transients. Why do you need 1/2-1 million transients? What purpose are they serving? The context matters enormously here and makes a huge difference between a yes and a no answer. _The answer depends on things you didn't mention.._

Comment: they store strings between 5 to 12 characters. They're used to limit API calls, because those API calls are expensive, not only for performance reason.

Comment: and do you have an object cache installed or is this falling back to the options table? If your results are stable and reliable enough to last an entire year is it worth creating a table and fetching them in advance?

Comment: It's in the options table. Is there a way to configure transients so that they are stored through other means?

Comment: Yes, use an external object cache and it will automatically prefer that instead. Redis or Memcached are good options. I would strongly recommend doing so as it provides a major performance boost to all aspects of WordPress

Comment: Any tutorial or resource that explains how to do this?

Comment: I don't have one I can recommend that will do all the things, installing an external object cache is something your host can assist with as you will need to choose one, e.g. MemcacheD, or Redis, as well as a drop-in to connect it to WP. At this point you're asking for software recommendations. It's also documented in the official WP docs and on lots of sites so a google search should yield thousands of results that are all very similar. It may be that your host doesn't provide any way of doing this, or that you use a host that already does this

Comment: Do you just have to install a plugin or is it more involved than that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends if you add an expiration time. If you do not add an expiration time then `autoload` will be yes. This means the option that stores this transient will be loaded on every request even if it's not used. With large numbers of transients this poses an issue purely in terms of memory.

I would recommend installing an external object cache if you haven't, as it will make transients both more efficient, and significantly faster ( as well as most of WordPress ).

If not, then a dedicated table may be better given the length of time your transients will stick around, but a large number of transients shouldn't cause major issues if they have expiration dates.

It may actually be more efficient to implement caching on the API with the expensive endpoints rather than in the consuming WordPress install. You should contact their maintainers.